# CFZip Issue - Timing out before reaching Timeout Limit

Tags: coldfusion, cfzip

I am using `cfzip` to zip folders on my server, anywhere from 2mb to 5gb.

Its timing out on a folder that is 1.25gb and I get the following error:

> The request has exceeded the allowable
>   time limit Tag: cfoutput

It errors after 11 minutes and I have the following tag at the top of the page `<cfsetting requesttimeout="99999">`. So technically it should be waiting 1666.65 minutes before timing out, right?

It's dedicated so I can push it to the max.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zipping something that size it probably going to take a loooong time. With a file 5GB in size, I would also think you would start to get outofmemory exceptions as well.

I'd be inclined to step out of the Java process, and use *cfexecute* to run it at a native level using the command line (should be easy enough with whatever platform you are on).

Dropping that also into a cfthread is probably a good idea as well, and then working out some sort of alert system when it is complete sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could try shoving the process into a thread. Those things rock out forever.